# Каким вы видите дизайн нашего сайта? [Важный опрос!]

Tags: обсуждение, design

Друзья, чтобы наш сайт продолжал развиваться, необходимо дать разработчикам знать, каким мы видим его будущее.

Пожалуйста, выскажите свои предложения, связанные с внешним видом сайта: цветами и формой различных элементов (стрелок за и против и т. д.), шрифтами, общей цветовой гаммой (это касается таких надписей, как заголовок вопроса, пункты меню, титульное название сайта и др.), фоном страниц...

Прикрепляйте конкретные изображения, давайте ссылки на прочие ресурсы — всё это будет полезно.

Взгляните на другие сайты сети Stack Exchange и обратите внимание на элементы, имеющие особый дизайн там. (Например: https://travel.stackexchange.com/, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/, https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/, https://photo.stackexchange.com/.)

Когда появятся предложения, давайте их обсуждать! Друг с другом можно и нужно не соглашаться или соглашаться — в конце концов, в споре должен родиться самый оптимальный вариант.

Подробнее (на англ.): [Responsive Design Themes - What can sites customize and how can they get changes implemented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319274/379531)

P. S. Если у вас есть возможность продублировать свой ответ на английском, пожалуйста, сделайте это.

Answer (score 2):

А чем плох наш дизайн? У нас, насколько мне помнится, был другой дизайн. Этот лучше, усовершенствован вроде.  Кстати, когда я захожу с другого компьютера, у меня открывается непонятный дизайн: много лишних картинок,  на странице сайта идет снег. Невозможно читать и писать.

Answer (score 2):

«Чтобы наш сайт продолжал развиваться, необходимо дать разработчикам» задание поразмыслить о расширении опций редактора в части различия дефис/тире и выделения ударной буквы. С народным творчеством и смекалкой на этом поприще (трЁхднЁвный и пр. урОдцы) надо прекращать, ибо несолидно.

Предполагая, что задача об ударных очень трудная или даже невыполнимая, предложу ввести один сигнальный цвет для текста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Мне очень нравится дизайн **[Большого Вопроса](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/profile189428/)**, которого кто только не скоммуниздивал  (почему бы и нам не присоединиться, м?) и который сам... эээ... базируется на майловских [Ответах](https://otvet.mail.ru/).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У Ответов есть категории, из плевел которых можно вылущить зёрна рацио, как, например,

из категории "Наука, Техника, Языки: Гуманитарные науки / Естественные науки / Лингвистика/ Техника" забираем лингвистику

и из "Образование: ВУЗы, Колледжи / Детские сады / Школы / Дополнительное образование / Образование за рубежом / Прочее образование" берём школьные задания по русскому языку (во как!)

---

А сам дизайн - ну не весь БВ копируем, а шо нам трэба, как то:

> Профиль
>
> Уведомления
>
> Ответы
>
> Репутация
>
> Вопросы
>
> Комментарии
>
> Награды
>
> Избранное
>
> Личные сообщения
>
> Избранное
>
> Настройки
>
> Анкета
>
> Черновики
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в Личном - ЛК - кабинете - большие буквы, диалоги и картинки - мечта Буратино и Алисы!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вообще полазить по бэвэшным закоулкам...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю почему, но мне видится оформление нашего сайта (или хотя бы его названия), выполненное в красных тонах. Не таких броских, чтобы выжигало глаза, и не темных, чтобы выглядело уныло и скучно. Примерно таких, которые я подобрал, создавая оформление плашек для блога:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Некоторые соображения насчет логотипа:

- я бы выделил особым оформлением букву Р и ставил бы на нее акцент в остальных элементах дизайна, например фавиконе;
- Р может быть «обернута» не лентой, как на приведенном выше концепте, а, например, скрижалью. Но эта идея мне не нравится тем, что исторически русский язык плохо связан со скрижалями. Другое дело — поток из кириллических и глаголических букв, следующий по траектории ленточки.
- остальную часть названия я бы просто написал красивым шрифтом;
- на фоне можно было бы сделать опять же некий набор из кириллических и глаголических символов (и слов из них?), как на этом кадре из видео «Арзамаса»:
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]